# Firebird Listener like TableDependency in SQL Server

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I am working on a C# (Visual Studio 2019) Form application and I need to fetch some table data from a Firebird database. For SQL Server, I am doing it successfully with TableDependency but in Firebird I am trying to do something similar to listen any record inserted in a Firebird table. Can anyone you please help? Listener needs to listen always if there is a new record in a table.

Comment: You will need to define an on insert trigger that posts an event, and then listen for that event to occur.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have inserted trigger and event also. But I am trying to develop a listener for that event. I dont know if BackgroundWorker will do the task for me or i have to generate something to listen. Clueless right now. Any help please ?

Comment: I don't really program in C# anymore, so I can't readily recall, but you need to use `FbRemoteEvent` to listen for events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var events = new FbRemoteEvent(@"database=localhost:Some.FDB;user=sysdba;password=masterkey"))
            {
                //events.RemoteEventCounts += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Event: {e.Name} | Counts: {e.Counts}");
                events.RemoteEventCounts += (sender, e) => rinIt(e); ;
                events.RemoteEventError += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {e.Error}");
                events.QueueEvents("SHOOTSALES");
                Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void rinIt(FbRemoteEventCountsEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Event: {e.Name} | Counts: {e.Counts}");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient